¿Cual es el shortcut o atajo de teclado para mostrar las propiedades o las opciones de un widget de Flutter en VSC en MacOS?

Existe un shortcut en windows que es "Ctrl + espacio" que muestra un submenu con las opciones de la propiedad, cual sería para mac?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Hola, prueba "fn + control + espacio"

Gracias Andres, esa combinación de teclas funciono perfecto!

En mac es el mismo control + barra espaciadora.
ese atajo sirve para sugerir opciones, para que me muestre otra propiedades, pongo una coma (,) antes y luego el atajo.


Gracias por tu respuesta... me pasa que cuando uso VSC y presiono "command + barra espaciadora" me abre spotlight o barra de búsqueda.  Desde configuración de vdc  configure el atajo con "command + I" y me funcionó bien...  Si uso otro IDE como Cursor si me funciona bien "command + barra espaciadora". no se porque pero bueno!!   igualmente gracias

hola buenas noches y como seria para ver las propiedades en Android Studio
